# How to update sdist package of mysql-connector?

Tags: python, mysql-connector, sdist

I am trying to update sdist package of mysql-connector (from 2.1.6 to 2.2.3, window7) using 'pip install -U mysql-connector', but have failed. See below:

Anyone encountered the same issue and any possible solutions? Many thanks.

[image: How to update sdist package of mysql-connector]

Answer (score 0):

Try updating pip

```
python -m pip install -U pip
```

And then the

```
python -m pip install -U mysql-connector
```

Or download the latest version of
https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/python/

Comment: Delete the mysql-connector                                                                            " pip uninstall mysql-connector   "                                                                  download the latest version of   https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/python/